# ¿Cómo hacer un refresh de un ListBox de asp con Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dropdownlist, listbox

Tengo un listbox que quiero que se actualice después de hacer un insert con una llamada Ajax, pero no logro hacerlo, cuando lo intento, salen los elementos del listbox duplicados.

Éstos son mis elementos de Asp

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsers" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control"
                    ForeColor="Black">
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <div>
                    <div>
                        <label id="lblListaCorreos" class="form-control label label-success">Correos por lista</label>
                        <asp:ListBox ID="lstCorreosLista" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:ListBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Aquí lleno mi ListBox dependiendo del elemento seleccionado de un DropDownList

```
var elementoSeleccionado;
                $('#ddlUsers').change(function () {
                    $('#lstCorreosLista').empty();
                    debugger
                    elementoSeleccionado = $('#ddlUsers option:selected').attr('value');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: getBaseUrl() + "checklist.aspx/ListadoUsuariosAjax2",
                        data: "{'Lista':'" + elementoSeleccionado + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {

                            //$('#lstCorreosLista').append("<option value='0'>Correos</option>");
                            $.each(response.d, function (i, item) {
                                debugger
                                $('#lstCorreosLista').append($("<option></option>").val(item.Mail).text(item.Mail));
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Aquí hago una llamada Ajax para hacer un Insert

```
 $('#btnNuevoCorreo').click(function () {
                        debugger
                        elementoSeleccionado = $('#ddlUsers option:selected').attr('value');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            url: getBaseUrl() + "checklist.aspx/AddMail",
                            data: "{'mail':'" + $("#txtNewMail").val() + "','lista':'" + elementoSeleccionado + "'}",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (response) {
                                alert(response.d);
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

Quiero que cuando llegue al success de la llamada ajax del insert, mi listbox se actualice, pero no logro hacerlo, alguna idea

Answer (score 0):

```
var elementoSeleccionado;
            $('#ddlUsers').change(function () {
                $('#lstCorreosLista').empty();
                debugger
                elementoSeleccionado = $('#ddlUsers option:selected').attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: getBaseUrl() + "checklist.aspx/ListadoUsuariosAjax2",
                    data: "{'Lista':'" + elementoSeleccionado + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {

                        //$('#lstCorreosLista').append("<option value='0'>Correos</option>");

                        //Elimina los elementos 'Option' antes de agregar nuevos

                        $('#lstCorreosLista').remove();


                        $.each(response.d, function (i, item) {
                            debugger
                            $('#lstCorreosLista option').append($("<option></option>").val(item.Mail).text(item.Mail));
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

Prueba con limpiar los elementos "option" antes de colocarlos de nuevo en tu función "success"